# if radio button checked appear and hide some input field - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have radio input called products
here is some example of my code

```
<input type="radio" id="product_1"class="products" value="1" >                           class="products">
<label for="product1">product_1</label>
<input type="radio" id="product_2" 
value="2"class="products">    
<label for="product2">product_2</label>
<input type="radio" id="product_3" 
value="3"class="products">
<label for="product3">product_3</label>


<div class="col-xs-12  class1" id="class1" >
<div class="form-group">
<select id="user_nationality" name="nationality_id" class="form-control ">
<option value=""></option>
@foreach($myproduct as $product)
<option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option></select></div></div>





$("body").on('click' , ".products" ,function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class1").hide();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class3").show();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class4").show();
        }else if($(this).val() == '2'){
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class1").show();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class3").show();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class4").show();
        }else{
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class1").hide();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class2").hide();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class3").hide();
            $(this).closest('.row').find(".class4").hide();
        }
    });
```

when I click on value 1, or value 2, and move between them there is no problem
My problem is when I choose value 3 and then go back to select value 1 or 2, it hides all input and nothing appears like it used to.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please share some HTML. Also, why you handle that `.class2` one only in one place? Read [ask], [edit] and create a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , I edit my question , its just an example of my code

Comment: why is your `</select></div></div>` *inside* the `@foreach`?

Comment: Also, could you show an example where you don't use `@foreach` but some actual markup? It's pretty easy, open dev tools, inspect element (your `<select>`) and copy the markup and edit it for the question purpose.

Comment: Also, why is that extra `class="products">` wondering in your HTML at the far right?